# How can I make my own Crud Repo with Pure Java without Spring, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, crud, repo

We have a CrudRepo from a framework which anyone can use:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface CrudRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {
```

However, I want to create my own CrudRepository with pure java ( with JDBC ).

Can someone give me some links on how to do this? I can't find any.

Maybe someone has some examples I can follow?

I want to have something like what I previously mentioned, but I don't know which Repos I should extend, I don't understand how to configure queries to the database and when I should write SQL ( CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE ) queries:

```
public interface MyOwnRepository<T, ID> {
   <S extends T> S save(S entity);
   <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);
   Optional<T> findById(ID id);
   boolean existsById(ID id);
   Iterable<T> findAll();
   Iterable<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids);
   long count();
   void deleteById(ID id);
   void delete(T entity);
   void deleteAllById(Iterable<? extends ID> ids);
   void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T> entities);
   void deleteAll();
}
```

The same as Hibernate but on Pure Java.

Comment: Unless you want to connect to multiple relational databases, you don't need an interface.  Create an SQL class that connects to the database, disconnects, and does SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE on your specific tables.  Use prepared statements.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I want to accept all values like void delete(T entity); and use it from any database

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an SQL class I created for a Bible application using MySQL.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class SQL {

    private int insertCount;

    private Connection connection;

    public boolean connect() {
        try {
            String[] params = createConnectionStrings();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
            this.insertCount = 0;
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    private String[] createConnectionStrings() {
        String[] connection = new String[3];
        String host = "bible-database.caaitaoyrsgp.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
//      host = "localhost";
        String port = "3306";
        String user = "ggleblanc";
//      user = "root";
        String useSSL = "?verifyServerCertificate=true&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true";
        useSSL = "?useSSL=false";
        String schema = "";
        schema = "/bible";
        String password = "********";
        String driver = "jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port;
        driver += schema + useSSL;
        connection[0] = driver;
        connection[1] = user;
        connection[2] = password;
        return connection;
    }

    public void close() {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean createBibleTables() {
        String[] sql = new String[7];
        
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `bible` ");
        builder.append("DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ; "); 
        sql[0] = builder.toString();
        
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("USE `bible` ;");
        sql[1] = builder.toString();
        
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bible`.`verse` ;");
        sql[2] = builder.toString();

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bible`.`book` ;");
        sql[3] = builder.toString();

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bible`.`book` ( ");
        builder.append("  `bookID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, ");
        builder.append("  `bookShortName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, ");
        builder.append("  `bookName` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, ");
        builder.append("  PRIMARY KEY (`bookID`)) ");
        builder.append("ENGINE = InnoDB ");
        builder.append("COMMENT = 'Book of the Bible'; ");
        sql[4] = builder.toString();

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bible`.`verse` ( "); 
        builder.append("  `verseID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "); 
        builder.append("  `bookID` INT NOT NULL, "); 
        builder.append("  `chapter` INT NOT NULL, "); 
        builder.append("  `verse` INT NOT NULL, "); 
        builder.append("  `text` TEXT NOT NULL, "); 
        builder.append("  PRIMARY KEY (`verseID`), "); 
        builder.append("  UNIQUE KEY `BOOK` (`bookID`,`chapter`,`verse`)) "); 
        builder.append("ENGINE=InnoDB; "); 
        sql[5] = builder.toString();

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bible`.`lastCreated` ( ");
        builder.append("    `timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL) ");
        builder.append("ENGINE = InnoDB ");
        builder.append("COMMENT = 'The last time the bible database was created';");
        sql[6] = builder.toString();

        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            for (int i = 0; i < sql.length; i++) {
                statement.executeUpdate(sql[i]);
            }
            connection.commit();
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int insertBook(String title, String text) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("INSERT INTO `bible`.`book` ");
        builder.append("(`bookID`, `bookShortName`, `bookName`) ");
        builder.append("VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?);");
        String sql = builder.toString();

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
        String sql2 = builder.toString();

        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, title);
            statement.setString(2, text);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql2);
            rs.next();
            return rs.getInt(1);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public void insertVerse(int bookNumber, int chapter, int verse, String text) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("INSERT INTO `bible`.`verse` ");
        builder.append("(`verseID`, `bookID`, `chapter`, `verse`, `text`) ");
        builder.append("VALUES (DEFAULT, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
        String sql = builder.toString();
        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setInt(1, bookNumber);
            statement.setInt(2, chapter);
            statement.setInt(3, verse);
            statement.setString(4, text);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            insertCount++;
            if (insertCount > 250) {
                connection.commit();
                insertCount = 0;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void insertTimestamp() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("INSERT INTO `bible`.`lastCreated` ");
        builder.append("(`timestamp`) ");
        builder.append("VALUES (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);");
        String sql = builder.toString();
        try {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.executeUpdate();
            connection.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have created it for specific app, but I need a repository that can be useful for any application. I need that it be like repos in Hibernate , CrudRepository etc.
I don't know how to make my own @Repository for queries

Comment: @Mary:  Fine.  Go reproduce Hibernate.  I posted this answer for the people who want a practical solution using JDBC.

Comment: Good! So can you tell me what should I do to make my public interface MyOwnRepository<T, ID> { work?
If I extends Repository<T, ID> , it will work. But how can I do without extends Repository?

Comment: @Mary: I have no idea how to produce a complex project like Hibernate.  I'm a simple programmer that likes to get work done.